# Multithreading Lock 2 threads didn't show anything

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I just learning Multithreading and now im trying the lock feature, what i tried in my code here is to show the `myText` every 2 seconds but in the console it didnt show anything.

```
class Program
{
    string Text = "";
    long Counter = 0;
    string Source = "abc def ghi";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadStart testThread1Start = new ThreadStart(new Program().WriteThread);
        ThreadStart testThread2Start = new ThreadStart(new Program().ReadThread);

        Thread[] testThread = new Thread[2];
        testThread[0] = new Thread(testThread1Start);
        testThread[1] = new Thread(testThread2Start);

        foreach (Thread myThread in testThread)
        {
            myThread.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public void WriteThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (Source != null)
            {
                lock(this)
                {
                    Text = Source;
                    Counter = Counter + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void ReadThread()
    {
        long myCounter = 0;
        string myText = "";
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (myCounter < Counter)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    myText = Text;
                    Console.WriteLine(myText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The counter in `ReadThread` is always 0, why is that? is it still locked or something?

Comment: Nothing to do with threading. You are creating a new instance of `Program` each time, so your threads are operating on their own instance. `new Program().WriteThread` and `new Program().ReadThread`

Comment: Rob has correctly identified the main problem. However, please note that you also have a theoretical thread-safety issue, in that you are accessing shared data without synchronization; i.e. the `Counter` variable. Without marking it `volatile`, the compiler is free to optimize access in a way that would prevent one thread from seeing changes. There is also the problem that `long` is 64 bits wide, and on x86 the variable would not be updated atomically, so trying to read unsynchronized could result in seeing a partially-updated value. Finally, your `ReadThread()` never updates `myCounter`.

Comment: @Rob oh i see, so i tried to make another class for the threads, and make the thread static. but how can i sent a variable from WriteThread to ReadThread?

Comment: @Mirza Keep everything the exact same as you've orignially posted. But, at the start, write, `var program = new Program()` and then use `new ThreadStart(program.WriteThread)` and `new ThreadStart(program.ReadThread)`. Also note the issues Peter brought up

Comment: Thanks @Rob n @ Peter Duniho :)